# How to copy from CSV's column A to SQL table's Column B

Tags: sql, csv, copy

I have thousands csv files to import in the database. However, there are 2 columns which are out of 63 bits limit.
How to import these columns into my database table? 
As far as I know, when using "copy..from..", the column name should be identical.

Comment: Please, specify the database and tools you are using.

Comment: Sorry. I am suing postgresql with "copy" command.

Comment: Ok. Did you try 'copy' with one of the files? What was your error?